# Python array unpacking error: need more than 3 values

Tags: python, arrays

I am fairly new to Python and am trying to compare some values stored in an array. when I run the code, I get the error:
    ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack.
my code is:

```
walls = ['300', '300', '300', '500']
for a, b, c, d in walls:
    if int(a) <= x <= int(c):
            if int(b) <= y <= int(d):
```

It's the 'for' line that throws the error. I know there are solutions to this online but none of them were for an array, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Quick FYI, in Python they are called Lists (The implementation is a Dyanamic Array similar to a Java/C# ArrayList or Ruby Array)

Comment: The `for` is iterating on your list, so the first time it runs the loop, it gets `'300'`.  This can be unpacked to `('3', '0', '0')` (your "3 values").  The answer by @w0lf shows you how to do what you intend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should become:

```
walls = ['300', '300', '300', '500']
a, b, c, d = walls # this line replaces the `for` loop
if int(a) <= x <= int(c):
    if int(b) <= y <= int(d):
        pass # or do something...
```

The initial version of the code iterated through every item in `walls` and tried to assign each of them to your four variables.

So, essentially, each iteration of the `for` loop tried to do something like:

```
a, b, c, d = '300'
```

Comment: As an alternative, changing the `walls` definition to `walls = [( '300', '300', '300', '500' )]` would avoid having to rewrite the rest of it. Although, it would leave behind a rather useless `for` loop that way...

Comment: @twalberg:   I don't care for your suggestion.  There is no reason to nest the data structure work around incorrect code.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski True, but it is entirely possible that the eventual use case would involve lists of tuples - something to actually iterate over - so it's probably still worth noting....